# Any way to stop ExpressJS sending Set-Cookie headers for static resources?

Tags: javascript, cookies, express

I have a problem where Chrome is not sending cookies with certain requests (Images - perhaps due to how I am loading them through JavaScript).  There are a lot of them, and Express is creating a separate session for every one of them.  This means that a single page load can set up 50 or so sessions.

Is there anyway of stopping static resource requests setting up new sessions in Express 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the middleware that's serving the static resources to before the session middleware:

```
// static first
app.use(express.static(...));

// sessions after
app.use(express.session(...));
```

Comment: Yep that did the trick. I'll accept the answer later when it lets me. Cheers.